# Switch between two images onclick

Tags: javascript, html

This question has been asked before, but none of what I've found works. I need to switch an image to another on click, and then back with another click.

```
<img id="searchicon" src="ddg.png" width="26px" height="26px" 
     onclick="this.src = ((this.src === 'ddg.png') ? 'logo.png' : 'ddg.png');">
```

This should work. `onclick` should be comparing `src` to `ddg.png` and returning true, replacing `src="ddg.png"` with `src="logo.png"`. However, it doesn't. If I change the original `src` to `logo.png` (or change the order of the operator), the operator will switch to `ddg.png`, but not back to `logo.png`. I have no clue why this is happening. No console errors are being produced. I have also tried writing this operator in a separate file and linking it in, as well as writing `if..else` statements. They all will switch from `ddg.png` to `logo.png`, but not the other way.

Comment: I would confirm exactly what `this.src` returns, as it is not matching what you think it should (The way you have written it, it must match EXACTLY including the case). Try `onclick="alert(this.src)"` and see what you get

Comment: It works fine for me , check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mz765jpg/1/

Comment: Got it. `this.src` was returning an absolute path, not a relative one. Thanks OJay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your src is referencing a file from your local system, it will not be equal to ddg.png, instead try the absolute path file://yourpath/ddg.png

Answer (score 0):

Small jQuery script written for the same. Its just a basic.

http://jsfiddle.net/35cfzfv4/

HTML

```
<img src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg" class="swapimg">
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var dimg = "http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg";
    var imgswitch = false;
    $('.swapimg').click(function(){
        if(imgswitch){
             $(this).attr('src','http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_01.jpg');
             imgswitch = false;
        }else{
             $(this).attr('src','http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/df/img/sample/img_02.jpg');
             imgswitch = true;
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
<img src="http://dizzyfrinks.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/65sprite.jpg" onclick="swap(this);"/>
```

**script**

```
var swap = function (img) {
    img.src = 'http://dizzyfrinks.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/65sprite.jpg' === img.src ?
        'http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/gadgetlab/sprite.jpg'
    : 'http://dizzyfrinks.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/65sprite.jpg';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me .
check this fiddle : [TOGGLE IMAGES](http://jsfiddle.net/mz765jpg/1/)

```
<img id="searchicon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi0uj.png?s=32&g=1" width="26px" height="26px" 
     onclick="this.src = ((this.src === 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi0uj.png?s=32&g=1') ? 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuFJV.jpg?s=32&g=1' : 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi0uj.png?s=32&g=1');">
```

Try checking whether you have specified the image path right.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I was expecting a relative path and instead got an absolute path. Thanks to OJay for suggesting outputting `this.src`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the browser will return the `src` of an image as the full URL, your code will not match the filename. Either use the whole URL to match (although this can be quite lengthy) or just look for a partial match

e.g.
full URL

```
<img id="searchicon" src="ddg.png" width="26px" height="26px" 
     onclick="this.src = ((this.src === 'http://www.whateveryoursiteis.com/ddg.png') ? 'logo.png' : 'ddg.png');">
```

or just check for the occurrence of that filename somewhere in the string

```
 <img id="searchicon" src="ddg.png" width="26px" height="26px" 
         onclick="this.src = ((this.src.indexOf('ddg.png') > -1) ? 'logo.png' : 'ddg.png');">
```

Although bear in mind the new src that you set it to must be either absolute, or a relative path in regards to the HTML page that it is on, the examples above assume that your pictures are in same directory as your html page